# How to make jQuery load starts when the other load(s) finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery so I don't know much about it, however I read about the **.load()** function which makes an ajax connection and shows the result of the page to the specific html element. What I was trying to do was that load three different div on the same page.

Example:

```
$("#abc1").load("result1.php",{"name:"namex});
$("#abc2").load("result2.php",{"name:"namey});
$("#abc3").load("result3.php",{"name:"namey});
```

Is there any way to make sure that the other **.load()** function only run when the first one has loaded and so on?

Comment: without being snarky: http://api.jquery.com/load/ is where that functionality is exactly explained. the 3d parameter is a callback that fires when the request is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [callback](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function).

```
$( "#abc1" ).load( "result1.php", {"name:"namex}, function() {
    alert( "Load 1 was performed." );
    $( "#abc2" ).load( "result2.php", {"name:"namey}, function() {
        alert( "Load 2 was performed." );
    });
});
```

Comment: consider the above example and can you show other user how would you achieve that ? like where the alert is , i need to put the other load there and so on?

Comment: That's it @user5871514

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$("#abc1").load("result1.php", function() {
    $("#abc2").load("result2.php", function(){
        $("#abc3").load("result3.php", function(){
            alert("All load performed.");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you removed the data being sent in the requests? Given this code the requests will not work in the same way as the OP intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact way you want:

```
$("#abc1").load("result1.php",{"name:"namex}, function(){
    $("#abc2").load("result2.php",{"name:"namey}, function(){
        $("#abc3").load("result3.php",{"name:"namey});
    });
});
```

Load callback is explained here: http://api.jquery.com/load/